# IDE para desenvolvimento de games

Tags: engine

Gostaria de saber quais as engines que possuem IDE própria e se essa IDE possui sistema interno de versionamento, também gostaria de saber para quais plataformas elas compilam...

Comment: Cara, uma IDE excelente para desenvolvimento de Jogos, é a Unity 3D, segue o link para você conhecer melhor: https://unity3d.com, ela compila para diversas platagormas e você desenvolve códigos em Javascript e, ou C#, é simples de utilizar e o proprio site do unity tem diversos tutoriais para iniciantes.

Answer (score 3):

Uma gratuita e boa é o Unity 3D, ele compila para praticamente todas platoformas e sim, possui versionamento.
É possivel programar os código em C# ou javascript

além disso o help deles é muito bom, com ele você já consegue entender bastante das funcionalidades.
Na internet existe bastante material também.
Agora se você quer algo menos robusto e mais fácil tem outras ferramentas como Construct 2, Stencyl que 
nem exige programação, é possível fazer muitas coisas com drag and drop